# django-profiles: How do I show the profile after login?

Tags: python, django

I am very new to django and web development. I came across django-profiles app so I decided to give it a shot. According to the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles/src/tip/docs/overview.txt) for django-profiles, the `/profiles/<username>` url will display the profile of the user. What I can't understand is how to send the username from login.html to `/profiles/<username>`.

Here is my login.html:

```
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
<div id="content-main">

 <form method="post" action="/profiles/?username={{ user.username }}">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="id_username">{% trans 'Username:' %}</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" id="id_username" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <label for="id_password">{% trans 'Password:' %}</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" />
    <input type="hidden" name="this_is_the_login_form" value="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="submit-row">
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}" />
  </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('id_username').focus()
</script>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your own login view and redirect the user at the end, according to its username:

```
def login(self, request):
    # check if login is correct and authenticate the user

    # redirect user
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/profiles/'+request.user.username)
    # OR better solution with reverse
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('module.view_profile', args=(request.user.username,)))
```

---

If you're using the default login view (furnished with Django) and you just want to redirect to a "static" URL (with no username), you can just define a setting `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` with the redirection URL, which is used if no `next` parameter is given in the URL.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/my_profile/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
HttpResponseRedirect('/profiles/'+request.user.username)
```

in your login view on successful login,